# angularjs input file onchange error in jhipster webapp

Tags: angularjs, jhipster

AngularJS v1.5.8

```
<input type="file"   onchange="angular.element(this).scope().uploadImage()" />

$scope.uploadImage = function(){
            alert("change");
        }
```

error in console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'uploadImage' of undefined
>       at HTMLInputElement.onchange

Comment: i got answer
html
    <input type="file" onchange="angular.element(this).scope.uploadImage()">

controller
        angular.element(document.body).scope.uploadImage = function() {
            alert("change");
        }

thanks all

Answer (score 0):

I think you have setup angular wrong, it should work like this:-

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {

  $scope.uploadImage = function() {
    alert("change");
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

    <input type="file" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().uploadImage()" />

  </div>
```

Comment: thanks,i use jhipster to create App ,it is not worked in jhipster webapp

Answer (score 0):

Try as like as given below :

**HTML**

```
  <input
       type="file"
       ng-model="file"
       name="file"                                
       onchange="angular.element(this).scope().uploadImage(this)"
                    />
```

**AngularJS**

```
  $scope.uploadImage = function(elements) {

      let file =  elements.files[0];   
  }
```

See : [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/yutefuzexe/edit?html,js,console,output)

Comment: thanks,but it is  not worked in jhipster